# Why am I getting a segue when I click "OK" on my error displayAlerts?

Tags: ios, swift

Every time I do not enter a username or password, or I enter an incorrect username or password, I get an error alert telling me what the problem is. When I click "OK", I get an unwanted segue to my Sign Up view.

```
 @IBAction func logInButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var error = ""
    if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {
        error = "Please enter a username and password."
    }
    if error != "" {
        displayAlert("Error", error: error)
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text, password: password.text) {
        (user: PFUser?, signupError: NSError?) -> Void in

        if signupError == nil {

            println("logged in")



        } else {

            if let errorString = signupError!.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {

                error = errorString as String

            } else {

                error = "Check your internet connection or try again later."

            }

            self.displayAlert("Could Not Log In", error: "Check your username and password.")

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Don't know if this is related, but:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToMenu", sender: self)

    }

}
```

Comment: So, is viewDidAppear called when you click "OK"?

Comment: @BenKelsey i think you need to write above code in another method but not in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Show us the code for displayAlert()

Comment: Is it possible you have connected the segue in the interface builder?

Answer (score -1):

I think it is the second part of your post that is performing the segue. I think that there is still a PFUser for the device your running the program on even if a proper sign in that you created wasn't satisfied.